# Can anyone identify this cattleya alliance hybrid?

Tags: identification, orchids

[image]I have lost all tag information for this cattleya alliance and need help identifying it.

Comment: Do you know where the plant came from?

Answer (score 2):

I think it is an intergeneric hybrid named *Laeliocattleya* Purple Cascade 'Fragrance Beauty'

I found no photograph without copyright, but [here you can see one](https://www.flickr.com/photos/shaggy67/8116331082/in/photolist-6WajnC-krYhvz-7QJfeM-7QJh4c-dndjsN-9Cnsze-9CqnMd)

Answer (score -1):

You might find it among these pix.  Just Google some of the name for pictures and many of what comes up are identified. There's actually one in there that looks like it; maybe you posted that one.

[https://www.google.com/search?q=cattleya+alliance&client=firefox-a&hs=teG&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&channel=sb&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=mOmMU4e8INCFqgbtgYGgBw&ved=0CEEQsAQ&biw=1361&bih=870](https://www.google.com/search?q=cattleya+alliance&client=firefox-a&hs=teG&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&channel=sb&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=mOmMU4e8INCFqgbtgYGgBw&ved=0CEEQsAQ&biw=1361&bih=870)

This website appears to have a very similar picture, but without a real name.  Maybe you can email them.

http://journeysandjonquils.blogspot.com/2012/03/winter-travels-part-7-national-orchid.html